# Create custom timer job which should run only on Application Server running Timer Service

Tags: custom-timer-job

I would like to create a timer job which should run only on Application Server running Timer Service. I am little bit confused after reading couple of blog and came up with construtor based on my understanding.

```
internal class NewJob : SPJobDefinition
{
    public const string JOB_NAME = "New Job";

    public NewJob()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public NewJob(SPWebApplication webApp)
        : base(JOB_NAME, SPFarm.Local.TimerService, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
    {
        Title = string.Format("{0} {1}", JOB_NAME, webApp.DisplayName);
    }

    public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
    }
}
```

Am I in the right path?

Comment: SPServer should be the third parameter as per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.spjobdefinition.aspx)

Comment: @AmalHashim Don't take this the wrong way, but there is really no point in providing a link to MSDN SP documentation. It's useless.

Comment: @SlavenSemper that link contains the Signature of the SPJobDefinition constructors. So I think it makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting the timer job to be run on a specific server then use below snippet

```
class TimerJobCustom : SPServerJobDefinition
{   
    public TimerJobCustom(): base()
    {
    }
    public TimerJobCustom(string jobName, SPServer server): base(jobName, server)
    {
        this.Title = jobName;
    }
    public override void Execute(SPJobState _jobState)
    {
        Logs.LogMessage(Logs.Log_INFO, Logs.Log_severity_verbose, "Timer Job - Server specific is running on ");
    }
}

public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    TimerJobCustom myJob = new TimerJobCustom("Server Timer Job", SPFarm.Local.Servers["Server"]);

    SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule();
    schedule.BeginHour = 1;
    schedule.EndHour = 2;

    myJob.Schedule = schedule;
    myJob.Update();
}
```

**Specify the server name in feature activation event**

Comment: what if we add a new server to the farm with TimerJob Role. Is there a way where we do not have to mention any server name?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati if you use `SPFarm.Local.TimerService` then the job will run on all servers which has `OWSTimer` service running. If you want to execute the service only on a specific server then follow my answer. You can modify it in such a way that you can read the server name from feature xml file. This will enable you to change the server name in future.

Comment: That's exactly i asked for, need to run timer job on servers running TimerJob Service.

Comment: OK my bad I read you want to run it only on Application Server.